# How to use the result of a BashOperator task as argument of another Airflow task?

Tags: airflow, databricks

I need to pass a **job_id** parameter to my object **DatabricksRunNowOperator()**. The **job_id** is the result of executing the `databricks jobs create --json '{myjson}` command.

> `$ databricks jobs create --json '{myjson}'`
>
> {job_id: 12}

```
import os
import subprocess    
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.databricks_operator import DatabricksRunNowOperator

def pull_function():
    returned_output = subprocess.check_output("echo ti.xcom_pull(key='jobid_CreateCreateRobot')")
    return returned_output


dag_CreateRobot = DAG(dag_id='CreateRobot', 
                      default_args={'owner': 'eric', 
                                  'email': [],
                                  'depends_on_past': False, 
                                  'start_date':'2019-09-16 16:48:28.803023', 
                                  'provide_context': True}, 
                      schedule_interval='@once')

CreateRobot = BashOperator(dag=dag_CreateRobot, 
                                 task_id='CreateRobot', 
                                 bash_command="databricks jobs create --json '{myjson}')")\

RunRobot = DatabricksRunNowOperator(dag=dag_CreateRobot, 
                                    task_id=ti.xcom_pull('RunCreateRobot'), 
                                    job_id=pull_function(), 
                                    databricks_conn_id='myconn', 
                                    json={'token': 'mytoken' })

RunRobot.set_upstream(CreateRobot)
```

I wrote this code for explaining my goal but it does not work. How can I do for using the result of a BashOperator task into other task that depends of it?

Comment: Hi, you need to use XCOM (Cross-Comunication) to transfer data between tasks.

Check this link: https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms

Comment: @A.Villegas yes, I tried to use it but I fail. Can you adapt my code to a works solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bash command in the `BashOperator` needs to be `$ databricks jobs create --json '{myjson}'`

i.e.

```
CreateRobot = BashOperator(dag=dag_CreateRobot, 
                            task_id='CreateRobot', 
                            bash_command="databricks jobs create --json '{myjson}')",
                            xcom_push=True #Specify this in older airflow versions)
```

The above operator when executed pushes the last line of the output to xcom. (https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/operators/bash_operator.html)

The `xcom` value can be accessed using :

```
ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='CreateRobot')
```

Comment: I obtained this error: "airflow name 'ti' is not defined"

Comment: pull function needs to be in this way - 

`def pull_function(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    ret = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='CreateRobot')
    print(f'ret:{ret}')`